# AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'Listen'

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition, uigesturerecognizer, listen

the speech recognition is not working here is my code :

```
robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
   print ("Robot: I'm listening")
   audio = robot_ear.listen(mic)

you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio)

print(you)
```

but the computer does not response to what I spoke:

```
Robot: I'm Listening
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python learn\code\nghe.py", line 7, in <module>
    audio = robot_ear.Listen(mic)
AttributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'Listen'
```

please show me how can I fix this :((

Comment: pls let us know the version of "speech_recognition" , you can find that by running the command `pip freeze`

Comment: From error statement code is different which is leading to Error because of `Listen` which is capital and in your code you have `listen` l in small  which is perfect so give proper error traceback with that code